# How to write a show-ref command in jgit?

Tags: git, jgit

JGit doesn't have a ShowRefCommand for getting the current references of all branches.
Is there a way to write ShowRef using jgit?

Answer (score 3):

Should be trivial to do. For a start, the format is just an iteration through files in the '.git/refs' directory, so you could do it with a shell script:

```
find refs -type f | awk -- '{print "echo `cat " $1 "` "  $1 }' | sh
```

However, in the JGit API you can do the same by iterating through the repository's references, which is returned by the 'getAllRefs' command:

```
Map<String, Ref> refs = repo.getAllRefs();
Set<Entry<String, Ref>> values = refs.entrySet();
for (Entry<String, Ref> entry : values) {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().getObjectId().getName() + " " + entry.getValue().getName());
}
```

Feel free to contribute it to JGit!